# How to read passed parameters

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i tried to read passed parameter,
for example:
shell:

```
MyApplication.exe -t 1233123
```

MyApplication Code:

```
dim tt as string = GetArgo(0).toString()
```

i want to get the "1233123" (i tried Me.Startup but i there is no Startup event in my form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get hold of the arguments by calling [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx):

```
Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

And then you can iterate through this array just like you would any other array. Remember that the first item in the array is the file name of the executing program.